# How to find and array object from another object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have two object arrays objectsData and objectsPurchaseData. I want to show that particular data was purchased. See the code below for reference.

```
var objectsData = [
{
"id": "1234abc",
"productName":"laptop1",
"img":"url1"
},
{
"id": "234abc",
"productName":"laptop2",
"img":"url2"
},
{
"id": "1234pqr",
"productName":"laptop3",
"img":"url3"
}
]
```

In this way I have object array for objects now for purchased products

```
var objectsPurchaseData = [
{
"id":"1234abc",
"product":"laptop",

},
{
"id":"1234pqr",
"product":"laptop"
}
]
```

This is what I have done

```
objectsData.map((data) => (
<img src={data.img} style={{...(((data.id === '1234pqr' )) ? {opacity: '8'} : {opacity: 'none'}) />
))
```

My intention is to show product image as opaque when purchased. It perfectly applies for only 1 item, but, what about multiple items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `(data.id === '1234pqr' )` try out this: `objectsPurchaseData.some(purchaseItem => purchaseItem.id === data.id)`